# MOC3020X phototriac: Does minimum latch current affect other specs of the IC?

Tags: thyristor, phototriac

I use MOC3020 IC to control a thyristor for AC mains voltage. My project works as expected and I would like to make an improvement on the current consumption, as I saw that there are other MOC302X ICs that use less current to latch:

[image: tmp_Sour2108]

The datasheet does not mention other differences between MOC302X ICs series, and I wonder if using less current to latch the phototriac presents and disadvantages.

Found another datasheet, still no mention of differencies: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/moc3023m-d.pdf

And it looks weird to me, that they made different versions ICs that can handle different currents.

1. Why not make only one version needing the smaller current option (5mA)? Engineers can compensate with using larger resistors.
2. Are there drawbacks (that the datasheet does not mention) for using the IC that needs less current to latch rather than the ones that need more mA to latch?

Comment: Do you mean phototriac rather than photodiac?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes. Edited the Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question title, I'd say "no".

> The datasheet does not mention other differences between MOC302X ICs series

True. The main difference between MOC30XX series are the off-state voltages (250V, 400V, 600V, 800V, etc) and zero-crossing circuit (MOC303X and MOC304X have).

> Why not make only one version needing the smaller current option (5mA)? Engineers can compensate with using larger resistors.

Different products could be for different cost targets i.e. ones with lower triggering current are more expensive. So if you want to trigger with lower current then you'll pay more.

> Are there drawbacks (that the datasheet does not mention) for using the IC that needs less current to latch rather than the ones that need more mA to latch?

One possible drawback is the effect of leakage current that is possibly generated by other external circuits connected to the output terminals i.e. as the hold (or latch) current gets lower the risk of having turn-off-related problems due to the "external" leakage current gets higher.

Answer (score 2):

1. The lower trigger current is a result of superior LED performance at that current and/or more sensitive phototriac performance. If they made them all conform to the lower current specification it would cost more to make and they could not sell them as cheaply. It's possible that (over time, these parts are very old) things have improved and they can actually make them all conform to the tighter specification for the same *cost*, but maybe not. Even if they can, it may make business sense to charge the customers who need more sensitivity a higher *price*. There are many examples of this kind of thing- for example, bipolar transistors may be sold in several "beta bins" (eg. BC547A,B or C) with the higher gain transistors generally commanding a premium price. The term comes from the idea of parts coming off an assembly line, being tested and the better ones get dropped into a different bin from the lower performance ones- the term implies the manufacturing process is not fully controlled in order to yield all parts in one particular performance band.

   Note that volume prices are often not reflected in small quantity distributor prices.
2. There are likely no technical drawbacks in this particular case (but there could be price or availability drawbacks). If you are comparing two different products rather than performance 'bins' of a single product, then the more sensitive phototriac (which is only part of the transfer characteristics) **may** be more sensitive to unwanted dv/dt triggering, say with inductive loads, or might not commutate as well when very hot, for example.

Comment: Thank you! Both are helpful answers :)